# SQL Server database level roles for creating tables

Tags: sql-server, permissions, role

Is there a way to create or change a special role for creating tables? Our software developer team has `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles but they can not create new tables.

I read this article related to [database level roles.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017) I don't want to grant `db_ddladmin` role because there is too much permissions in this role.

So my question is how can i give creating and deleting tables permissions for a database? Views, procedures and functions are okay too. All I need is I don't want to grant permissions related to security, login or backup operations.

Comment: Should they be able to only create tables or can they also create views, procedures, functions etc?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Views, procedures and functions are okay too. All i need is i don't want to grant permissions related to security, login or backup operations.

Comment: Then why is db_ddladmin too much?

Comment: May db_ddladmin database level role edit or delete database audits? If answer is quite ok,  db_ddladmin looks suitable for us. Also is it best practice to grant software developers this level role? Thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

**If you want to create a role with specific rights, you could do this:**

```
CREATE ROLE CreateObjects
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO CreateObjects
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO CreateObjects
GRANT CREATE FUNCTION TO CreateObjects
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO CreateObjects
GRANT ALTER ANY SCHEMA TO CreateObjects
```

**Create the test user:**

```
CREATE LOGIN testlogin with password = 'StrongP@SSWORD123'

CREATE USER Testlogin FOR LOGIN Testlogin
```

**Add the user to the role:**

```
ALTER ROLE CreateObjects ADD MEMBER Testlogin
```

**Test the user's permissions:**

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'testlogin'

SELECT SUSER_NAME(),USER_NAME()

(No column name)    (No column name)
testlogin   Testlogin


CREATE TABLE dbo.test(id int)

DROP TABLE dbo.test 
REVERT
```

**Result**

```
Commands completed successfully.
```

**Or like Tom stated, add the user to the db_ddladmin role.**

```
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER testlogin
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own database role for this, and then grant CREATE TABLE at the database level:

```
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO rolename
```

You can of course also grant this permission directly to the users, if you wish.

Comment: This is not sufficient to create a table. Try to create a user, grant him only CREATE TABLE, and make him a member of db_datareader, db_datawriter. When this user attempts to create a table, he'll got the error  2760, because he has no permission on schema

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks for catching that. ALTER permission for the schema is also required. Just as Randi proposed (in the above reply that I didn't when I wrote mine :-) ).